# Spring - How to insert images in db in integration tests

Tags: java, mysql, spring, junit, base64

I have this folder structure similar to this one:

```
main
  |--
test
  |-- java
      |-- com.my.app
          |-- unit
          |-- integration
  |-- resources
      |-- sql
          |-- // some folder with sql files
```

Inside `integration`, I have several classes with tests that look like this:

```
@Test
@Sql(value = "/sql/test_data.sql")
public void test() {...}
```

So far, so good.
But now, I added a table that has a `blob` field, used to store images, and in my app I convert that image (using a converter) to `base64` and return that `base64` string.

I'm able to unit test that converter, but now I want to test the class that use that converter, and I need to insert some images in the h2 db.

How can I do that? I'm not about the syntax, I'm asking where to put that images? inside test/resources? how to use the images inside the sql files in test/resources/sql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution :) I created a `test/resources/images` folder, and inside `test/resources/sql/test_data.sql`:

```
INSERT INTO table (id, encoded64px) VALUES (1, FILE_READ('classpath:images/image-64px.jpg'));
```

Also, make sure you have permissions over the images.